# Linker Command Failed with Exit Code 1 (use -v to see invocation) with Google Ads

Tags: xcode, swift, admob

I recently made the switch from iAd to Google Ads and it seems to be working fine on the simulator. But whenever I try to run it on my iOS Device I get this error:

[image]

What's wrong with this?

Comment: All those *directory not found* warnings and that *does not contain bitcode* should be key indicators as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same error occurred with my project and following solution works!

Please check that, if you have enabled or disabled bitcode in your xcode project.

Navigate to "**Project dashboard > Build settings > 'search for bitcode' > 
enable it if it disabled or disable it if its enabled**"

And then clean + build the project again.

Comment: Now I keep getting a SIGABRT.